# Efficient use of JAX for conditional function evaluation based on an array of integers

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, conditional-statements, vectorization, jax

I want to efficiently perform conditional function evaluation based on an array of integers and other arrays with real numbers serving as input for those functions. I hope to find a JAX-based solution that provides significant performance improvements over a for-loop approach that I describe below:

```
import jax
from jax import vmap;
import jax.numpy as jnp
import jax.random as random

def g_0(x, y, z, u):
    return x + y + z + u

def g_1(x, y, z, u):
    return x * y * z * u

def g_2(x, y, z, u):
    return x - y + z - u

def g_3(x, y, z, u):
    return x / y / z / u

g_i = [g_0, g_1, g_2, g_3]
g_i_jit = [jax.jit(func) for func in g_i]

def g_git(i, x, y, z, u):
    return g_i_jit[i](x=x, y=y, z=z, u=u)

def g(i, x, y, z, u):
    return g_i[i](x=x, y=y, z=z, u=u)


len_xyz = 3000
x_ar = random.uniform(random.PRNGKey(0), shape=(len_xyz,))
y_ar = random.uniform(random.PRNGKey(1), shape=(len_xyz,))
z_ar = random.uniform(random.PRNGKey(2), shape=(len_xyz,))

len_u = 1000
u_0 = random.uniform(random.PRNGKey(3), shape=(len_u,))
u_1 = jnp.repeat(u_0, len_xyz)
u_ar = u_1.reshape(len_u, len_xyz)


len_i = 50
i_ar = random.randint(random.PRNGKey(5), shape=(len_i,), minval=0, maxval= len(g_i)) #related to g_range-1


total = jnp.zeros((len_u, len_xyz))

for i in range(len_i):
    total= total + g_git(i_ar[i], x_ar, y_ar, z_ar, u_ar)
```

The role of "i_ar" is to act as an index that selects one of the four functions from the list g_i. "i_ar" is an array of integers, with each integer representing an index into the g_i list. On the other hand, x_ar, y_ar, z_ar, and u_ar are arrays of real numbers that are inputs to the functions selected by i_ar.

I suspect that this difference in nature between i_ar and x_ar, y_ar, z_ar, and u_ar is what could be difficult to find a JAX way that would be more efficient replacement of the for loop above'. **Any ideas how to use JAX (or something else) to replace the foor loop to obtain 'total' more efficiently?**

I have tried naively using vmap:

```
g_git_vmap = jax.vmap(g_git)
total = jnp.zeros((len_u, len_xyz))
total = jnp.sum(g_git_vmap(i_ar, x_ar, y_ar, z_ar, u_ar), axis=0)
```

but this resulted in error messages and led to nowhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the best way to do this is with [`lax.switch`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.lax.switch.html), which allows dynamically switching between multiple functions based on an index array.

Here's a comparison of your original function with an approach based on `lax.switch`, with timings on a Colab GPU runtime:

```py
def f_original(i, x, y, z, u):
  total = jnp.zeros((len(u), len(x)))
  for ii in range(len(i)):
    total += g_git(i[ii], x, y, z, u)
  return total

@jax.jit
def f_switch(i, x, y, z, u):
  g = lambda i: jax.lax.switch(i, g_i, x, y, z, u)
  return jax.vmap(g)(i).sum(0)

out1 = f_original(i_ar, x_ar, y_ar, z_ar, u_ar)
out2 = f_switch(i_ar, x_ar, y_ar, z_ar, u_ar)
np.testing.assert_allclose(out1, out2, rtol=5E-3)

%timeit f_original(i_ar, x_ar, y_ar, z_ar, u_ar).block_until_ready()
# 71 ms ± 23.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit f_switch(i_ar, x_ar, y_ar, z_ar, u_ar).block_until_ready()
# 4.69 ms ± 37.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```