# Defining the correct vectorization axes for JAX vmap with arrays of different shapes and sizes

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing, array-broadcasting, jax

Following the answer [to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75421210/efficient-use-of-jax-for-conditional-function-evaluation-based-on-an-array-of-in), the following function that
'f_switch' that dynamically switches between multiple functions based on an index array is defined (based on 'jax.lax.switch'):

```
import jax
from jax import vmap;
import jax.random as random

def g_0(x, y, z, u): return x + y + z + u
def g_1(x, y, z, u): return x * y * z * u
def g_2(x, y, z, u): return x - y + z - u
def g_3(x, y, z, u): return x / y / z / u
g_i = [g_0, g_1, g_2, g_3]


@jax.jit
def f_switch(i, x, y, z, u):
  g = lambda i: jax.lax.switch(i, g_i, x, y, z, u)
  return jax.vmap(g)(i)
```

With input arrays: i_ar of shape (len_i,), x_ar y_ar and z_ar of shapes (len_xyz,) and u_ar of shape (len_u, len_xyz), out = f_switch(i_ar, x_ar, y_ar, z_ar, u_ar), yields *out* of shape
(len_i, len_xyz, len_u):

```
len_i = 50
i_ar = random.randint(random.PRNGKey(5), shape=(len_i,), minval=0, maxval= len(g_i)) #related to 

len_xyz = 3000
x_ar = random.uniform(random.PRNGKey(0), shape=(len_xyz,))
y_ar = random.uniform(random.PRNGKey(1), shape=(len_xyz,))
z_ar = random.uniform(random.PRNGKey(2), shape=(len_xyz,))

len_u = 1000
u_0 = random.uniform(random.PRNGKey(3), shape=(len_u,))
u_1 = jnp.repeat(u_0, len_xyz)
u_ar = u_1.reshape(len_u, len_xyz)

out = f_switch(i_ar, x_ar, y_ar, z_ar, u_ar)
print('The shape of out is', out.shape)
```

This worked. **But, How can the f_switch function be defined such that the result out of out = f_switch(i_ar, x_ar, y_ar, z_ar, u_ar) has a shape of (j_len, k_len, l_len) when the function is applied along the following axes: i_ar[j], x_ar[j], y_ar[j, k], z_ar[j, k], u_ar[l]? I am not sure about how ** Examples of these input arrays are here:

```
j_len = 82;
k_len = 20;
l_len = 100;
i_ar = random.randint(random.PRNGKey(0), shape=(j_len,), minval=0, maxval=len(g_i))
x_ar = random.uniform(random.PRNGKey(1), shape=(j_len,))
y_ar = random.uniform(random.PRNGKey(2), shape=(j_len,k_len))
z_ar = random.uniform(random.PRNGKey(3), shape=(j_len,k_len))
u_ar = random.uniform(random.PRNGKey(4), shape=(l_len,))
```

I tried to resolve this (i.e. with given input array to get output of shape: (j_len, k_len, l_len), with a nested vmap:

```
@jax.jit
def f_switch(i, x, y, z, u):
  g = lambda i, x, y, z, u: jax.lax.switch(i, g_i, x, y, z, u)
  g_map = jax.vmap(g, in_axes=(None, 0, 0, 0, 0))
  wrapper = lambda x, y, z, u: g_map(i, x, y, z, u)
  return jax.vmap(wrapper, in_axes=(0, None, None, None, 0))(x, y, z, u)
```

and to broadcast u_ar: `u_ar_broadcast = jnp.broadcast_to(u_ar, (j_len, k_len, l_len))`, and then apply it inside of the original f_switch. But, both of these attempts failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like maybe you want something like this?

```py
@jax.jit
def f_switch(i, x, y, z, u):
  g = lambda i, x, y, z, u: jax.lax.switch(i, g_i, x, y, z, u)
  g = jax.vmap(g, (None, None, None, None, 0))
  g = jax.vmap(g, (None, None, 0, 0, None))
  g = jax.vmap(g, (0, 0, 0, 0, None))
  return g(i, x, y, z, u)

out = f_switch(i_ar, x_ar, y_ar, z_ar, u_ar)
print(out.shape)
# (82, 20, 100)
```

You should read the in_axes from bottom to top (because the bottom `vmap` is the outer one, and is therefore applied to the inputs first). Schematically, you can think of the effect of the maps on the shapes as something like this:

```
                               (i[82], x[82], y[82,20], z[82,20], u[100])
(0, 0, 0, 0, None)          -> (i,     x,     y[20],    z[20],    u[100])
(None, None, 0, 0, None)    -> (i,     x,     y,        z,        u[100])
(None, None, None, None, 0) -> (i,     x,     y,        z,        u)
```

That said, often it is easier to rely on numpy-style broadcasting rather than on multiple nested vmaps. For example, you could also do something like this:

```py
@jax.jit
def f_switch(i, x, y, z, u):
  g = lambda i, x, y, z, u: jax.lax.switch(i, g_i, x, y, z, u)
  return jax.vmap(g, in_axes=(0, 0, 0, 0, None))(i, x, y, z, u)

out = f_switch(i_ar, x_ar[:, None, None], y_ar[:, :, None], z_ar[:, :, None], u_ar)
print(out.shape)
# (82, 20, 100)
```